# How do I post checkbox values to php script using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

How do I use the below to send to a php page the value of each of the checkboxes in mysql is either inserted into a new row or updates an exisiting column

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
 var $n = jQuery.noConflict(); //Jquery no conflict 

     $n("#btnsubmit").click(function() {

             var allChkbox=$n('input[name=cats[]]');

              jQuery.each(allChkbox, function(i, singlecheckbox) {
                alert(singlecheckbox.value+" is "+ singlecheckbox.value);
             });


        });
 // ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $n = jQuery.noConflict(); //Jquery no conflict 

     $n("#btnsubmit").click(function() {

             var allChkbox=$n('input[name=cats[]]');
              var data = [];
              jQuery.each(allChkbox, function(i, singlecheckbox) {
                data[singlecheckbox.value] = singlecheckbox.value; // this line is strange, the index seems not be singlecheckbox.value
                // alert(singlecheckbox.value+" is "+ singlecheckbox.value);
             });
              $.ajax({type:"GET", url: "test.php", data: data,
success:function(records){}, error: function(request, status, err){}});


        });
```

The test.php will receive the request by get.